# get all tableview cells, even the non visible

Tags: objective-c, uitableview

I need to loop through tableview cells in different sections to calculate something in each one; however when I try to do this:

```
CustomCell * c = (CustomCell *)[self.table cellForRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:i]
```

if the section "i" is not visible I can't get the content inside.

I must say that the content I want to calculate in each cell will vary before I call the calculate method, so I can't populate the tableview then calculate.

Any ideas?

Comment: if you tell what type of calculation, then we can suggest you the way, otherwise getting all cells is nearly impossible, since the TableView is typically configured to re-use cells, which means it will not create cells equals to number of rows.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should not be performing *calculations* based on the content of `UITableViewCell` objects, because they fundamentally belong to the *presentation* layer; there should be no calculations going on in the presentation layer, only hiding and displaying things.

For calculations, you should go directly to the layer from which your `UITableViewDataSource` gets its data (presumably, that would be your *model* classes) and do the calculations there. Better yet, move the calculation to the model layer, and put out a method for getting it on demand.

If you are modifying the existing code written by someone else, start by examining the `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method in the `UITableViewDataSource` to see from where it gets its data. Presumably, that place has all the data available, regardless of whether it is showing on the screen or not.